# Multiple values for one var in json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

There is probably a really simple solution, but I can't figure out how to save multiple Strings in one variable. And how can I access it then?
Example:

```
Character(
    name: "Finn",
    imagePath: "assets/images/finn.png",
    description: "example",
  ),
```

but I want more Imagepaths.
I actually thought it'll work like that:

```
Character(
    name: "Finn",
    imagePath: {
 "assets/images/finn.png",
"assets/images/finn2.png",
}
    description: still example",
  ),
```

But how I said I can't figure it out.

Comment: @anmol.majhail And how can I access it? Isn't it character.imagePath[1]? It actually doesn't work like that, but character.imagePath worked.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question includes `JSON`, so it seems like you might want to serialize your class to and from JSON eventually. JSON has the concept of an `array` which corresponds to a Dart `List`.

So, `imagePath` becomes a Dart `List<String>`, which you can write as `['first path', 'second path',]` and access as `imagePath[0]`, etc.

Of course, the Dart JSON encoder/decoder handles converting Dart lists to JSON arrays. Your JSON would end up looking like `..., "imagePath" : [ "first path", "second path" ], ...`

Comment: I have it exactly like that but I don't get a value for imagepath[0]. I'm really confused because I also don't get an error and the complete app isnt working anymore (the design is the same, but nothing happens if I click items).

Comment: Update the question with an actual non working example.